# Code runs without error or warningsm but it crashes

Tags: c

The code is about trying to find the largest number possible from an array of given numbers, by using char array instead of an int array. There are no warnings nor errors popping up off on my build message. Yet when I ran this code, it crashes. Is something wrong in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    const char **X = (const char **)a;
    const char **Y = (const char **)b;

    int char_len = strlen(*X) + strlen(*Y) + 1;

    char XY[char_len];
    strcpy(XY, *X);
    strcat(XY, *Y);

    char YX[char_len];
    strcpy(YX, *Y);
    strcat(YX, *X);

    return strcmp(YX, XY);
}

int main (void) {
    int i,n;

    printf("enter number of salaries: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
   
    char *array[n];
    int j = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

    printf("\nenter the salaries: ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("\t%s", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("\nOutput: \n");
    qsort(array, j, sizeof(array[0]), cmp);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s", array[i]);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Edit 1 : I moved the *char array[n] after the scanf it worked. However, it still crashes when it executes the qsort line.

Comment: `n;
    char *array[n];` - how many elements has `array`? (ie. what is the value of `n` when `array` is defined?)

Comment: i see i understand, i tried moving the *array[n] after the scanf. The code now runs and outputs from size of the array, elements of the array. However, still crashes at the qsort line.

Comment: `warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]` - get a better compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem you have is this:

```
scanf("\t%s", &array[i]);
```

`array` is an array of pointers, and this will pass the address of one of those pointers to scanf, where `%s` will write a string over the top of the pointer (giving you a garbage pointer and, if the string is long enough, writing over further pointers in the array.

What you want is to allocate some memory for the string and read it into that, and then store the pointer to that memory into the array.  If you're using a POSIX system, there's an easy way to do that:

```
scanf("\t%ms", &array[i]);
```

This will use malloc to allocate exactly enough memory for the string read (including the NUL terminator) and store that pointer into the pointed-at array element.

Note also, the `\t` is the format string is irrelevant -- it just skips leading whitespace, which the `s` conversion specifier does anyways.

Answer (score 0):

`n` is not initialized. Hence, undefined behavior when declaring `array[n]`

```
int i,n;
char *array[n];
int j = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

Imagine if `n` was assigned zero on startup.  Changing the value of n on the subsequent `scanf` line won't resize the array.

Further, even if `n` was sufficiently assigned the length of the array, this is still undefined behavior:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    scanf("\t%s", &array[i]);
}
```

There's no memory allocation for each array entry.  Imagine that after you declare `char* array[n]` successfully, each pointer value in that array is undefined.  IF you are lucky, each element is NULL (0) and it will crash fast. But most likely, you get random memory.  And your `scanf` is copying a string into memory your program doesn't own.

Comment: i see, thank you very much. I tried moving both

int i,n;
char *array[n];

after the scanf, it works! but still crashes executing the qsort line.

Comment: Because you didn't allocate enough memory for each element within the array.  What address do you think `scanf("\t%s", &array[i]);` copies the typed user input into?  Do you know what `malloc` does?